# Will adding an index on a table of 2 million records be twice as slow as the same table with 1 million records?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 70 million records and there is an index missing. I want to calculate the time to add the index without backing up the table and doing the index on the backed up table.

I am just wondering if it will be twice as slow(linear) or if it is exponential.

database: mysql 5.0

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I have minimal experience on MySQL)

It should be somewhere in-between.

The absolutely lowest complexity of the whole operation would be the one that would appear when just reading all records in order, which is a linear process - `O(n)`. This is an I/O bound operation and there is not much that can be done about it - modern caching systems in most OS may help, but only in a DB that is in use and fits in the available memory.

In most SQL engines, indexes are some variation of a B-tree. The CPU complexity of inserting a single record into such a tree is roughly `O(log(n))`, where `n` is its size. For `n` records we get a complexity of `O(n log(n))`. The total complexity of the operation should be `O(n log(n))`.

Of course, it's not quite that simple. Computing the index tree is not really CPU-heavy and since the index pages should fit in RAM on any modern system, the operation of inserting a single node *when the tree is not rebalanced* would be close to `O(1)` time-wise: a single disk operation to update a leaf page of the index.

Since the tree does get rebalanced, however, things are probably a bit more complex. Multiple index pages may have to be commited to disk, thus increasing the necessary time. As a rough guess, I'd say `O(n log(n))` is a good start...

It should never come anywhere close to an exponential complexity, though.

EDIT:

It just occured to me that 70,000,000 B-tree entries may not, in fact, fit in the in-memory cache. It would depend heavily on *what* is being indexed. `INTEGER` columns would probably be fine, but `TEXT` columns are another story altogether. If the average field length is 100 bytes (e.g. HTTP links or 30 characters of non-English UTF-8 text) you'd need more than 7GB of memory to store the index.

Bottom line:

- If the index fits in the cache, then since building the index should be a single DB transaction, it would be I/O-bound and roughly linear as all the records have to be parsed and then the index itelse has to be written-out to permanent storage.
- If the index does not fit in the cache, then the complexity rises, as I/O wait-times on the index itself become involved in each operation.

Answer (score 1):

What thkala describes is true for inserting individual rows, but when creating a new index, no reasonable RDBMS will just do `n` inserts, rather it will construct the index directly starting with the leaf nodes. This process will almost certainly be IO-bound.

So, in practical terms, re-indexing time should be linear: twice as long for twice as many records.

Comment: True, building the index should be a single transaction. The time complexity, however, would depend on whether the index tree will fit in RAM or not. 70,000,000 index entries on a TEXT column could easily fill in several GB of in-memory cache...